# Android - Get the coordinates of a View dynamically

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-view

I'm making an app in which there will be an `ImageView` which will be animated upon clicking a `Button`. Now, I want to display the coordinates(X & Y) of the `ImageView` in a `TextView`.

How do I make a mechanism that'll keep fetching the coordinates of the `ImageView` dynamically even when it is being animated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using the Animator API you can set an animationupdatelistener and get the coordinates  on update.

Comment: Okay.... That is plausible. But I want to retrieve the coordinates of the `ImageView` throughout the time, not only during the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should start a new thread that updates the text in the `TextView`

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            final int centreX = imageView.getX() + imageView.getWidth()  / 2;
            final int centreY = imageView.getY() + imageView.getHeight() / 2;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    textView.setText(Integer.toString(centreX) + " " + Integer.toString(centreY));
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: Nope... Didn't work. The whole UI freezes at once and stops responding.